# I want the partial pagecurl effect ,not the full screen

Tags: ios, page-curl

Now I am developing an app on iOS, I need the pagecurl effect, but the all source code I   found was full screen! However, I only need the partial screen, not full screen. So I need  to know how to do it!

Could anybody provide an example for me?

Comment: Do some research on your own. Reformat your post to look mature. Edit it with code or approaches that didn't work and then you can expect some help.

Comment: In order to save time , I directly modify the code coding by leaves .

Comment: URL  is this       https://github.com/ole/leaves

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reference on the different forms of Modal Views contained in iOS, including the partial page curl, here: [on Tim Neill's blog](http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/).

Comment: exercise me ,  I have visited this blog yet . but   I stil  not found where introduced  the partial pagecurl???  It seems that the effect done by it is fullscreen.  could you give me more detail ??Thank you

Comment: Okay, you'll need to be more clear about what you actually want. But returning to the link I gave you there's a block of code containing four IBActions, one of which is called 'showCurl', that does the partial curl that I assumed you were looking for.

Comment: exercise me , It may be a little confuse  for my question.

Comment: This pagecurl is being used by a APP developed by me on IPAD . excetp the pagecurl part . I also have some other outlets . and the pagecurl part can not covert it.  Could you give me your e-mail??I can send you the preview picture

Comment: If you upload it and attach it here I'll have a look, but I'm still a little confused by what you want.