# How to fold back the edge of view controller in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-effects

I want to make a nice visual effect on my Map View Controller, which is folded back its right-bottom egde. When user taps on it there will be shown another controller using Partial Curl effect (this part of task is easy for me).

So my question is if it is possible to permanently fold back the egde of controller to achieve described visual effect (only visual, I know how to make transition)?

Comment: take a look @ this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361281/i-want-the-partial-pagecurl-effect-not-the-full-screen

Answer (score 1):

Use an image overlay on your controller which has the corner folder back within it. Ultimately it will always be folded back and never need to animate, since you say you already know how to do the fold animation. So the image is just needed to represent what you want until the fold is invoked.